# Not able to use FSI on VS code

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

since few days, I'm not able to use FSharp Interactive interpreter(Alt + Enter), it's giving me this message:
`*Failed to spawn FSI, please ensure it's in PATH*`

also, if I run the script, it give me `connect ENONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1.8397`

I'm using:
`- Ubuntu 16.04`
`- Visual Studio Code 1.28.2`
`- Ionide-sharp 3.28.0`

anyone have an idea to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I finally fixed it, but I'm not sure if what I did fixed it or not.

Anyways, here is what I did:
0. in cmd, type which fsharpi to get the fsi path

in VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Fsharp configuration
Fsharp:Fsi File Path and enter the result you got with which fsharpi
uninstall ionide-fsharp from VS Code extension > reload > reinstall
But this solution fixed the execution of the script but error syntax highlighting and code lens is not working.

Comment: On Windows I started getting something similar. I can execute scripts but my intellisense, type info, etc. is gone

Answer (score 4):

I think the main cause is the last update done. I have made a rollback and now everything is back to normal:

1. remove ionide-fsharp from VS code
2. click on https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/releases/download/3.27.0/Ionide-fsharp-3.27.0.vsix to download previous version of ionide (v 3.27.0)
3. unzip the file. once the file is unziped, you will have 2 text files and a folder named *extension*. Rename that folder **ionide.ionide-fsharp-3.27.0**
4. on your terminal, type:

   - > `cd ~/.vscode`
   - > `cd extensions/`
   - > `mv /home/####/Downloads/Ionide-fsharp-3.27.0.vsix_FILES/ionide.ionide-fsharp-3.27.0 .` (don't forget the dot at the end to move the folder to the new location )
5. it should add ionide.ionide-fsharp-3.27.0 into VS Code extensions
6. you need to turn off auto-update in VS Code (in VS Code, in the bottom left conner, click on Setting icon > click on Settings > in the field *Search setting*, type ***update*** and search, you should then search in the result for **Extensions: Auto Update**)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this just by installing .NET Core SDK from this link https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial